# Is there a Windows live USB similar to Ubuntu Live USB?

Tags: windows-7, liveusb

I'd like to have a Windows live in my USB to use on public computers. I use Ubuntu Live USB but I'd prefer Windows. Any pointers?

Comment: It’s very unlikely you will be able to change the boot order of a public machine.

Comment: Not officially, but there are some WinRE based community projects which can build a an USB or DVD bootable Windows system. But these systems don't provide a full Windows system there are a lot of differences. The tool for creating such live Windows system is named PEbakery.

Comment: @Robert - The author will still have to change the boot order to use those solutions though.

Comment: @Ramhound That's not an issue. It's possible %99 of the time.

Comment: From my understanding, though it is possible to create a Windows USB, there are some issues: 1. Updating Windows fails. 2. WinPE has a 72-hour time limit before automatically rebooting -- see https://support.arcserve.com/s/article/202807255?language=en_US And, of course, drivers may be missing if run on another PC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. It is "Windows ToGo". You can create such a USB with Rufus: https://rufus.ie/. Surely you need working Windows for that.

Comment: The OP can try it. Windows To Go has been discontinued a long while ago because it was too slow from a USB.  No modern Windows 10 on Windows To Go.

Comment: @John there are 300/200 R/W MB/s pendrives from which it works fine. Also Rufus can do that on external SSD.

Comment: @JJrussel - Whichever Windows you have a legitimate license to

Comment: It's only Microsoft's _Windows To Go_ __creation utility__ that has been discontinued and while Microsoft have indeed stated that they are not going to work on the official _Windows To Go_ feature any longer it does __not__ mean that _Windows To Go_ has been removed from Windows altogether. The fact is, you do need the _Windows To Go_ feature to be able to run Windows on many SoC platforms, such as ARM64 ones, and it would therefore be foolish of Microsoft to remove support for it. Which is why, you can still very much run the latest Windows 10 or Windows 11 as _Windows To Go_.

Comment: @Akeo where's the best place to download it? Do I need a license/product key to use it full function?

Comment: @JJrussel, you don't need a license (you can run Windows in trial mode) and you can download the official Windows ISOs [using Rufus](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/images/download.gif) or by going to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download (which is what Rufus accesses behind the scene to create the ISO links).

Comment: @Akeo I'd like to use Ventoy (a multi boot USB) instead of Rufus. Would that be possible?

Comment: I don't think Ventoy supports Windows To Go. But you are of course free to use whatever utility you prefer to create bootable media.

Comment: @Akeo Any idea where a can download the iso or img full version?

Comment: I indicated 4 posts above that you could [use Rufus](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/images/download.gif) or go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download.

Comment: @Akeo Yes you did. But wouldn't Rufus require me to...well...use Rufus? Can I download an ISO or IMG of Windows to go from Rufus? Also, wouldn't the Microsoft link be trial? My question was "full version". Thanks again!

Comment: All the ISOs downloaded by Rufus or from the link I gave you are FULL retail versions, and can be used to create _Windows To Go_ drives. Like almost every software this day, they will run as trial version, with all functionality (and, in the case of Windows, no time limit) until you enter a valid license key. Oh and you're not required to use Rufus with the ISOs you download through Rufus, since they are standard retail ISOs. You can just save them somewhere and use another application.

Comment: @Akeo Thank! What are the limitations of the trial version?